# prometheus_client/start_http_server two python script writing to the same server

Tags: python, prometheus

I would like to be able to have
one python script that :

- start the prometheus exporter server
- creat Gauge
- update Gauge

=> This I can do it

But I would like another python script able to connect to the same prometheus exporter server and would be able to write also on other Gauge

Is it possible?

Thanks

1rst script that works :

```
import prometheus_client
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Gauge
start_http_server(8000)
gh = Gauge('dht22ExtMedHum', 'Humidity claculate with the Exterior DHT22 Sensor ')
gh.set(-999)
```

But don't know how to connect to this server with another python scrip...